# Axes labels within numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

Does np.ndarray have the functionality of carrying axes labels?

Let's say that I have a 2-D array with dimensions being time and speed. I want to actually have both axes labels (time and speed values) embedded in an object, so that the object takes care of the axes whenever I do operations with the array (e.g. slice or even plot).

After searching for a while I haven't found anything. I was about to start coding such a class myself and then I thought about asking here, just in case I've missed something.

Thanks

### EDIT

Given the comments and answers so far, I think I haven't explained my self clear, or just the reasoning behind what I want is not clear due to an oversimplified example [time, speed].

In the field I work it's common to have recordings from multiple sensors, and then segment the data so that you have multiple samples/events. If each sensor captures a 1-dimensional signal across time, one have dimensions [Sensor, Event, Time] (dimension is implicit in the data itself).

When using pure numpy.ndarray, you'll end up with variables: `data`, a 3-D array with the recorded data; `sensor`, a 1-D np.recarray with all the information for each sensor (e.g. name, location, ...); `event`, a 1-D np.recarray with all the information for each sample/event (e.g. type, offset, ...); and Time, a vector with the time values.

What I want is to have all that information in a single object `mydata` and don't worry about basic manipulations (slicing). So that `mydata[0:3, 1:10]` will slice the corresponding dimensions accordingly.

I agree that things like plotting will be data specific, but I'll happily code a subclass of such object with some extra functions (e.g. `plot`).

### Why would this be useful?

**Readability**: Compare

```
data1 = data[0:3, 1:10]
sensor1 = sensor[0:3]
event1 = event[1:10]
time1 = time
```

with a simple

```
mydata1 = mydata[0:3, 1:10]
```

**Maintenance**: The second option is obviously easier to maintain and less prone to errors in the correct slicing of all associated variable.

**Convenience**: Having all this information in the same place allows to integrate useful and powerful function within the class. For example, if I create a derived class for time series (forcing to have a time axis), I can run time specific functions without having to specify time or sampling frequency (as this information is within the object itself). The idea is to have a base class carrying axes' labels, and specific subclasses will naturally arise when necessary (e.g. one for time series, one for video, one for topographic information, etc) incorporating specialized functionality.

### Close but not exactly

As @user2357112 mentioned, Pandas' DataFrame is close to what I'm looking for. But, apart from the fact that N-D arrays is still experimental, it seems to be too much oriented to a table-like behaviour (for what I've read so far), e.g. treating the first dimension differently than the others (items vs columns).

### Is it worth it?

The above may seem trivial, and not worth the effort, but I programmed a subclass of np.ndarray with such functionality a few years ago and I can assure you it made my life and code so much easier! (The specific application was similar to the example above [sensor, sample, time]). But that was back when I was learning python and the way I coded it isn't what you'll call pretty. It also has some fundamental faults, like the axes labels not following the same share-memory rules as np.ndarray.

Before embarking in the trouble of rewrite this thing and make it public, I wanted to know if there's something similar out there.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "axes information". Arrays certainly keep track of things like how many axes they have and how long each axis is. Are you asking whether you can label the axes and have the labels stick to the array? You might want to look into Pandas.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks. That was actually my question. And it seems that Pandas sort of does it, but it's still experimental for N-Dimensional arrays :-(

Comment: So let's say you have an array as a list of lists, just make another list inside your array, and then reference it by using [-1] as an index. Doesn't exactly take care of plotting it, but it does take out some hardcoding.

Comment: [numpy structured arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.rec.html) might be what you want.

Comment: For slicing, array[position,speed] doesn't make much sense, you could only represent integer or scaled values directly, and you might end up with a sparse array if the data is not regularly spaced... What's the purpose?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What you may be looking for is [`xarray`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/index.html).

---

From its documentation:

## xarray: N-D labeled arrays and datasets in Python

xarray (formerly xray) is an open source project and Python package that makes working with labelled multi-dimensional arrays simple, efficient, and fun!

Xarray introduces labels in the form of dimensions, coordinates and attributes on top of raw NumPy-like arrays, which allows for a more intuitive, more concise, and less error-prone developer experience. The package includes a large and growing library of domain-agnostic functions for advanced analytics and visualization with these data structures.

Xarray was inspired by and borrows heavily from pandas, the popular data analysis package focused on labelled tabular data. It is particularly tailored to working with netCDF files, which were the source of xarray’s data model, and integrates tightly with dask for parallel computing.

Comment: xarray's "dims" property it exactly what I was looking for! Whenever I talk about adding label to axes, everybody points me towards Pandas, but it can only add column titles for spreadsheet-like objects. Having the possibility to store the information that "Dimension 0 is the Y position, dimension 1 is the X position, and dimension 2 is the color channel index" is very useful to prevent mixups!

Answer (score 1):

`numpy` arrays are the abstract objects that you can use to build labeled tables and plots.  `pandas` pushes the table and data series angle, `matplotlib` the plotting angle.  And for large scale data storage, such as generated by supercomputer models, there are systems like NETCDF and HDF5.

You might want to look at how HDF5 handles dimension scales, and how `h5py` gives you access to them in `numpy`.

http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/dims.html

> Datasets are multidimensional arrays. HDF5 provides support for labeling the dimensions and associating one or “dimension scales” with each dimension. A dimension scale is simply another HDF5 dataset.

Creating an array from axes is a common `numpy` task.  `np.arange` and `np.linspace` create 1d arrays, `np.meshgrid`, `mgrid` and `ogrid` create 2d (or larger) arrays, which in turn are used to calculate values on a grid.  Note that `meshgrid` allows you to specify `ij` or `xy` styles, reflecting two conventions, rows/columns v plot horizontal/vertical axes.

```
 X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
 z = my_function(X,Y)
```

but plotting functions can take various forms of input:

```
 plot(x, y, z)   # 2 1d arrays and a 2d
 scatter(X,Y,Z)  # 3 2d arrays
 scatter(XYZ)    # 1 Nx3 array
```

So while this is a connection between the generating arrays and dependent one, this is a higher level of organization, one that your code has to maintain, not something that `numpy` does for you.

A comment mentioned `structured arrays`.  That can replace the `columns` of a 2d array with named `fields` (and by extension to higher dimensions), but it is most useful when working with diverse data loaded from CSV files.  They are more like the fields of SQL tables than the `y` coordinate of a plot.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the two options I could see working:

1. Some insane 5D Numpy array with loads of repeating elements and sub elements. (which will absolutely not help at all for one of the primary problems you are trying to solve, namely ease of indexing.)
2. Or Multi-Indexing and Pivot-Tables from Pandas

[Pandas Docs - Intro documentation for Pandas generally if you're unused to the library. This link will take you to the hierarchical-indexing / pivot table section](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/10min.html#reshaping)

[Pandas Docs - Multi/Hierarchical Indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html)

[Pandas Docs - Pivot Tables, Stacking and Unstacking](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/reshaping.html)

[An article of a worked example with LoTR script data](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-multiindex-in-pandas-to-level-up-your-analysis-aeac7f451fce)

Without some example data to know exactly what you're working with I could only copy paste some example code from these links.

True, it is Pandas. Which you said wouldn't meet your needs. But the thing you pushed back against was the limitation of only having labels on one axis. Hierarchical indexing is Pandas answer to this problem and Pivot tables give you easy (if initially obscure) methods for reshaping your data into the arrangements you need for a given purpose.

Also the accessing of elements and subgroups of data is incredibly easy, which was one of your main requirements.

From what I am aware of it also maintains the high mathematical performance typical of Pandas.